# Commit after creating .gitignore

Tags: git

If I commit all files and directories without.gitinogre file, and after that I create .gitignore file and add only it, files and directories that I added in my .gitignore file are added to git branch.

So, how can I commit all files without files and directories that are defined in .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the .gitignore files first.

`git -rm files-in-gitignore --cached`

Answer (score 0):

Add specific Files only:

```
git add [some files]       # add [some files] to staging area
git add [some more files]  # add [some more files] to staging area
git commit                 # commit [some files] and [some more files]
```